# Resources on the upcoming fork-join framework

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join

I'm looking for well organized information sources about how the upcoming jsr166y (fork-join, fences) and extras166y (ParallelArray, etc.) can be used - something from tutorial to expert level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IBM Developerworks website has a [good series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11137.html) on this, but the most informative source I've found is [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/brian-goetz-concurrent-parallel) by Brian Goetz, which is well worth an hour of your time. He spends the first 25 mins talking about the background, but then presents some great examples of the new framework.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the presentation as I don't remember seeing it. I guess I expected something like Java Fork-Join Concurrency in Practice book - maybe Brian is working on it? You know, I saw so many things about FJ (I even read Doug's article) but I felt the unorganizedness. I also think the Java community should start developing based on FJ.

Answer (score 2):

[Doug Lea homepage](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html), check also the [wiki](http://artisans-serverintellect-com.si-eioswww6.com/default.asp?W1)

Comment: I wouldn't consider Doug's page and the concurrency-interrest list as a well organized tutorial as I am already monitoring/subscribed to them.

Comment: what about the wiki I linked?

Answer (score 1):

[Brian Goetz](http://www.briangoetz.com/) gave an excellent talk at [Devoxx](http://www.devoxx.com) 08 called from Concurrent to Parallel on the fork join framework and the Parallel Array abstraction on top of it. You can view the video of the talk and the slides at [Parleys](http://www.parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#title=From%20Concurrent%20to%20Parallel;slide=1;talk=24576007)

Comment: Updated linkie: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/brian-goetz-concurrent-parallel

Answer (score 0):

Here is presentation with best practices when using fork-join framework for computations:

http://people.apache.org/~shade/talks/jeeconf-May2012-forkjoin.pdf