# Using scala actor framework as fork-join computation?

Tags: scala, actor, fork-join

Is it possible, in theory, to use the Scala Actor Framework to do a kind of asynchronous divide-and-conquer computation similarly to JDK 7's Fork-Join framework? If so, how could I express an FJ problem with the framework - for example, the tutorial mergesort concept? Code snipplets are welcome.

(I came to the idea based on a [resource video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/brian-goetz-concurrent-parallel) I've got in my other [FJ related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148125/resources-on-the-upcoming-fork-join-framework).)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Scala does have FJ style parallelism.  It's call futures and it's part of the actors library

```
import scala.actors.Future
import scala.actors.Futures._

def mergeSort[A <% Ordered[A]](xs : List[A]) : List[A] =  {
  // merge is not interesting, it's sequential.  The complexity lies in keeping it tail recursive
  def merge[A <% Ordered[A]](accum : List[A], left : List[A], right : List[A]) : List[A] = {
    (left, right) match {
      case (lhead::ltail, rhead::rtail) => 
        if (lhead <= rhead) merge(lhead :: accum, ltail, right)
        else merge(rhead :: accum, left, rtail)
      case (Nil, _) => accum reverse_::: right
      case _ => accum reverse_::: left
    }
  }

    // here's the parallel sort bit
  def sort[A <% Ordered[A]](xs : List[A], length : Int) : List[A] =  {
    if (length <= 1) xs
    else {
      val leftLength = length / 2
      val rightLength = length - leftLength
      val (left, right) = xs splitAt leftLength

      // fork
      val leftFork = future { sort(left, leftLength) }
      val rightFork = future { sort(right, rightLength) }

      // join
      val leftJoin = leftFork()
      val rightJoin = rightFork()

      // merge
      merge(Nil, leftJoin, rightJoin)
    }  
  }

  sort(xs, xs.length)
}
```

Now, to the heart of the question.  If Scala didn't have futures could you write one yourself based on actors.  Indeed.  It would look more or less like this.

```
import scala.actors.Actor 
import scala.actors.Actor._

object MyFuture {
  def apply[T](x : => T) : MyFuture[T] = {
    val future = new MyFuture[T]

    val act = actor {
      react {
        case sender : Actor => sender ! (future, x)
      }
    }

    act ! self

    future

  }
}

class MyFuture[A] extends Function0[A] {
  me => 

  lazy val result = receive {
    case (`me`, result) => result.asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def apply() = result
```

}

And you would use it like so

```
scala> val x = MyFuture(28 * 1000)
x: Foo.MyFuture[Int] = <function>

scala> x()
res4: Int = 28000
```

Comment: I tried your FJ example with list of size 400 and I don't get almost no cpu load (should be 100% on all cores, right?). Any exaplanation on that?

Comment: How this can be rewritten with scala 2.10, where they discourage from using blocking future()?