# What is the difference between CountDownLatch, CyclicBarrier and Phaser Concurrent classes?

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the difference between `CountDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier` and `Phaser Concurrent class`es ?
These classes works as a synchronizer. How they are different from each other?

Comment: I see some related questions on the right (as usual). You should find answers to your question there...

Comment: Also, read their javadoc.

Comment: Feel free to read the documentation on each; it spells it out pretty clearly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830904/java-tutorials-explanations-of-jsr166y-phaser/6831171#6831171

Comment: Please demonstrate research effort.

Comment: search on any search engine would have given you this.