# Multithreading - Wait for sub threads before creating a new thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating "big threads", let's name them A, B, C... and put them in a queue.
Each of these "big threads" are creating sub threads inside them. a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3...

What I do is checking if A is TERMINATED and then starting the B and so on. But when A is finished a1, a2, a3 is starting and running simultaneously, and A becames TERMINATED. So B is starting right after with b1, b2, b3. I don't want this happen. How can I check or make A wait a1, a2, b3 and then be TERMINATED?

I've simplified and anonymized the code but the basic idea is the same:

Here is where runnable foo class is created and added to the queue FYI:

```
RunnableFooClass rc = new RunnableFooClass();
Thread t = new Thread(rc);
```

Here is run method of runnable bar class("sub thread") created inside runnable foo class ("big thread")

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<Constants.THREAD_NUM; i++){
         //initialize t
         t.start
    }
}
```

Following code is in an endless loop:

```
if(jobQueue.peek().getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED){
    try {
        jobQueue.peek().join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(jobQueue.poll().getName() + "end.");
}
if(jobQueue.peek() != null){
    jobQueue.peek().start();
    System.out.println(jobQueue.peek().getName() + "start.");
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html

Comment: (Aside from your direct question) Running in an endless loop waiting for a thread to be TERMINATED is a terrible idea. join it instead. And why not take it out of the queue *before* running it? Then you don't need to "peek" - just wait for something in the queue.

Comment: If `jobQueue.peek().getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED`, why do you need to `jobQueue.peek().join()`?

Comment: +1 @MuratK. for Phaser. There are no sub threads in java. All new thread will be created as separate entity. So applying join will be tricky. Phaser can be used instead. https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-understanding-phaser

Comment: @RealSkeptic that endless loop is checking other things and adds new threads to the queue. How can I deal with it other than this ?

Comment: Have one thread that adds to the queue, and another that reads from it and takes care of it, for example. Without knowing the full details it's hard to help.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic .

Comment: It does not make sense to use three different threads to do three different tasks _in sequence_.  If you want to be sure that task B does not start until task A is finished and task C does not start until task B is finished, then the right way to do that is to perform tasks A, B, and C in a single thread.

Comment: Another way that sometimes makes sense is to submit tasks A, B, and C to a _single threaded_ executor.  (see [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution is to use `CountDownLatch`.

In thread A create a latch initialized `THREAD_NUM` and pass it to each subthread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    CountDownLatch latchA = new CountDownLatch(Constants.THREAD_NUM);
    for(int i=0; i<Constants.THREAD_NUM; i++){
         RunnableFooClass rc = new RunnableFooClass(latchA);
         Thread t = new Thread(rc);
         t.start();
    }
    latchA.await(); // wait for termination of all subthreads
}
```

Then, at the very end of the subthread's `run()`

```
latchA.countDown();
```

Comment: +1 for basic solution, however in long run Phaser is more beneficial. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830904/java-tutorials-explanations-of-jsr166y-phaser

Comment: @ankidaemon You're right Phaser is more advanced and allows more flexibility, but is less frequently used (in my experience). Personally, I tend to use simple structures when they are sufficient. Anyhow, thank you for pointing to the other question, it had some interesting answers.

Comment: Agreed with @noscreenname. Yes Phaser is less frequently used as I also didn't came across Phaser at my org

Comment: @noscreenname Tried, and now it's solved. Thanks. Thank you all.